# Preprocessor macro for universal framework in header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I'm on a legacy project and there's one codebase to build different frameworks for iOS, macOS, etc. In one of the public header files that is copied into the framework product, there is a preprocessor macro like this

```
 // MyObject.h
#ifdef TARGET_IOS
@import UIKit;
#endif
```

In the same header file, if I try to do

```
#ifdef TARGET_IOS
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *containerView;
#endif
```

The framework builds fine. However when I try to test out the framework in a separate app project, the compiler doesn't know what type `containerView` is on the type `MyObject`.

But of course if I just do

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *containerView;
```

without the preprocessor macro, in the separate app, it knows what type `containerView` is. Why is that? I thought that you tell the compiler on what to build with preprocessor macros. And then since that framework is built with that property `containerView` defined, it would work. But maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

### Edited

TARGET_IOS=1 in Preprocessor Macros of Build Settings for Debug and Release configurations.

Comment: Where is TARGET_IOS being defined?

Comment: @MobileBen It's being defined as `TARGET_IOS=1` in `Preprocessor Macros` for both Debug and Release configurations.

Comment: @Crystal have you ever found a solution?